# how can I recursively go thru all my security groups to export all Users to a CSV file

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Users" | Where {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'} | Get-ADUser -Properties Title,Department,LastLogonDate,telephoneNumber| Select Name,Title,Department,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName,LastLogonDate,telephoneNumber | Export-CSV -Path C:\ADExport\Users.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

My "Users" group contains other subgroups. How can I tell PowerShell to iterate thru all subgroups instead of pass and quit?

The subgroups may have additional groups

Example

```
 Users
      Location1
           Division1
           Division2
           Division3
                SubDivisionA
                SubDivisionB
      Location2
           Division1
           Division2
           Division3
                SubDivisionA
                SubDivisionB
```

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer, but this link might get you started: http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/build-recursive-functions-in-powershell,2-865.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Get-ADGroupMember](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852290) has a `-Recursive` parameter to get nested subgroup members, so you don't need to. Add that to your code.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Users" -Recursive | ...
```

---

**Help Links** (if available):

- Get-ADGroupMember is [`Get-ADGroupMember`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219308) (in module ActiveDirectory)